# How to flatten handsaw cut edge?

Tags: wood, woodworking

I have a piece of wooden board in the shape of the following image. The unit is in centimeters. And the board is 2.5cm thick.

[image]

On both sides, I've cut a 45-degree piece off using a Japanese pull-saw. The edge cut is not bad, and I did manage to saw according to the lines I drew. But when I try to attach two of such piece together, you can tell immediately that the 45 degree edge is not in perfect angle. It's not perfectly flat either.

I can't use a plane to flatten the edge because of its shape. I couldn't get a good grip, and the edge seemed to be pretty rough.

I've been trying to use a handsaw to fix the edge by attaching it to the edge while carefully sawing. It only solves a part of the problem. Is there a better way to flatten the edge (hopefully without a router)?

Answer (score 3):

Cutting a miter like that is best done on a table saw with a crosscut sled, or with a well tuned miter saw, or (failing either of those options) rough cutting the miter with a hand or circular saw and then dressing them with a hand plane or large disk sander. Given the dimensions your best option at this point is to use what's called a "donkey ear shooting board" ([shown here](http://www.theunpluggedwoodshop.com/mitre-shooting-board.html)) with an appropriate hand plane on a good solid workbench. For best results you will need a fairly sharp low-angle jack plane to perform this operation but it can be done with a standard jack or jointer plane if they are very well tuned. Best of luck!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say I don't have a table saw. I checked the article, but making that shooting board is very difficult (with precision) to me. What's weird is that it still manage to use a plane, to eventually get the angle right. I would think with the appropriate clamp I can also do it.

Comment: Well i guess you could just clamp it but the jig holds the piece and guides the plane at the same time. If you're interested only in getting the project done and not in developing your skills as a woodworker (no judgement:) just take it to a cabinet shop and ask them to cut if for you. The  results will be better than anything you can hope to bang together with a limited tool set and the cost should be minimal.